# What makes Dm/E sound Phrygian?

Tags: harmony

I was told by a jazz pianist that you can play Dm/E if you play in E Phrygian.
What makes Dm/E sound Phrygian? To me Am or Am7 would be a better chord for Phrygian but then I probably think of Phrygian in terms of church music theory and not jazz theory.

Comment: Note that you can also play Am7 in E Aeolian. Listeners will default to Aeolian over Phrygian if not exposed to that distinctive flattened supertonic.

Answer (score 5):

The characteristic tones of phrygian are flat 2 and perfect 5. They distinguish phrygian from aeolian and locrian.

Dm/E is E - D - F - A. Note E in bass suggests E is root. Other notes come from phrygian scale, in particular F is flat 2.

Note B or perfect 5 is missing, so in principal Dm/E doesn't distinguish phrygian from locrian (which would have Bb, flat 5), but as for most ears locrian sounds exotic, phrygian would be the first interpretation.

Am7 is certainly a valid chord for E-phrygian (or A-phrygian, I'm not sure which one you meant), but it doesn't contain its characteristic tones so it doesn't emphasize the mode.

Comment: You can play Am and have E as Mi (which is the finalis). This works in chant accompaniment. If it works in jazz I don't know.

Comment: Yes, I agree you can, it "fits". What I said that Am by itself won't suggest E phrygian strongly.

Answer (score 2):

1. Dm/E contains the pitches DEFA.
2. One can "fill in the blanks" with passing tones: say, GB and C.
3. The resulting scale is DEFGABC.
4. "Permuting" the scale gives EFGABCD, which is E Phrygian (in the modern sense, rather than the Gregorian sense).

The pitches of the Dm chord are "embedded" within the E Phrygian scale, just as they are with C Major or D Dorian. But the bass E suggests the possibility of E as the tonic.

Depending on context, your could "fill" Dm/E with other passing tones. For example, EFGABbCD, which would be E Locrian, origination from F major. Alternatively, EFG#ABCD, which would come from the A harmonic minor scale.

Comment: No.3 is a dead ringer for D Dorian!